# Download UIImage if needed and save it for later

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

So, i have an application with a tableview that shows images from web (doesn't matter from where)

when the view loads the downloads start, but i want to build a cache to download only the images that i don't have on the cache.

i've seen tutorials to download and save on disk, but how can i implement this validation?
only download IF not local, and if local show the local.

how can i get this images dynamically?

like almost using the method `imageNamed` so when i need to build the table view i just call `[MyClass getImageWithName:(name)` and if exists, return my image, if not put it on download queue

just to make things clear, my question is: "How can i get easily one image from documents folder?"

Comment: [This library has downloading and caching mechanism, check it out](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading)

Comment: Check if the file for the image exists. If not, download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following things:

```
- (NSString *)ImagesDirectoryPath
{
NSFileManager *fileManger = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
basePath = [basePath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Images"];
NSError *error;
 if(![fileManger fileExistsAtPath:basePath])
 {
    [fileManger createDirectoryAtPath:basePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
 }
return basePath;
}
```

This method will return Your Images Path under Document Directory

Now You have image Name So we will check in Images Directory whether its exits or not. if exits then use that img or download img and then store it
 // this code will be cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 NSString *strImgPath = [self ImagesDirectoryPath];
strImgPath = [strImgPath stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.png",imgName]];
 NSFileManager *fileManger = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 if(![fileManger fileExistsAtPath:strImgPath]) //Check wether image exits at Image Folder in Doc Dir
 {//file not exists
    UIImage *imgForCell =  [MyClass getImageWithName:imgName];

   if(imgForCell)
   {
    NSData *dataImg = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgForCell);
    if(dataImg)
    {
        [dataImg writeToFile:strImgPath atomically:YES];
    }
   }
    imgView.image=imgForCell; //Set Image in ImageView
 }
 else
 {//file exists
   NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strImgPath];
UIImage*imgFound = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData]; 
  imgView.image=imgFound; //Set Image in ImageView
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write a function that save/load your images.

Here is a example that show how you can save/load images from documents folder:
http://www.friendlydeveloper.com/2010/02/using-nsfilemanager-to-save-an-image-to-or-loadremove-an-image-from-documents-directory-coding/

But it is suggested to save the images in Library/Caches

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the link for reference. Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.